Beautiful Soup: find tag containing a string and other elements
I am trying to find <li> tags containing "Country: " as the inner text. The tag also contains other children (<a> ).
<li>
   Country:
   <a href="example.com">Germany</a>
</li>

Using soup.find("li", string="Country: ")
appears to work only if <li> contains the exact string and no other elements. Using regex soup.find("li", string=re.compile("Country: ")) returns no result either.
What is the correct query in this case?

The reason you can't do what you want is that soup.find(string=re.compile("Country: ")) finds the text node within the li element, not the li node, so the node name filter does not match.
One way to do this is to pass a filter function to soup.find, which accepts only li elements which contain a node matching the regex:
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<li>
   Country:
   <a href="example.com">Germany</a>
</li>""", features="html.parser")

country_re = re.compile("Country:")
def match_li_with_country(node):
    if node.name != "li":
        return False
    return bool(node.find(string=country_re))

country_li = soup.find(match_li_with_country)
print(country_li)

Another has the same idea, but does it manually: first find all li nodes, then filter them to find one that contains the string you want:
country_li = next((
    node for node in soup.find_all('li')
    if node.find(string=country_re)
), None)
print(country_li)

